# Laravel: OrderBy filter, then show all others?

Tags: laravel, filter

Let's say I have a bunch of job postings sorted by location.

How can I create a filter, to order the postings by filter, then show the rest below?

For instance, if I select New York, I want to see all NY job postings first, then show job postings in all other cities below the NY ones. Any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Let's say where is your code ?

Comment: I don't have any code yet - I am just thinking hypothetically how I can go about doing this - I am not sure where to begin.  Is it: 1. Make a filter to show NY listings, 2. below that, make a filter to show all non-NY listings?

Comment: you can merge two collections. one with the searched keyword and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do something like this:

```
$selectedPostings = Posting::where('city', '=', 'New York')->get();

$otherPostings = Posting::whereNotIn('city', ['New York'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from table_name order by `location` regexp 'New York' desc;
```